# Run macro when active cell is on specific columns

Tags: vba

I would like to run macro when active cell is only on column G,Q and Z.
How can i narrow it to just run on those 3 columns and not in range from G to Z?
Tried to set a 3 different target adreeses but it didnt work.

```
If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    Set A = Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("G4:Z2500"))
    If Not A Is Nothing Then
    Call macro
    Else: Call DeleteAllShapes
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the start.

```
if target.column=7 or target.column=17 or target.column=26 then exit sub
```

or

```
If not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G,Q:Q,Z:Z")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'etc
```